# Show and set custom column aliases inside json_agg

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Basing on following example:

```
WITH Table_A as (select 1 as AA),
    Table_B AS (select 2 as BB),
    Table_CD AS (select 3 as CC, 4 AS DD)
    
        
    select json_build_object(
      'X', (select json_agg(A.AA) from Table_A A)
    , 'Y', (select json_agg(B.*) from Table_B B)
    , 'Z', (select json_agg(CD.*) from Table_CD CD)
    )
```

1. Why is that if I did not specify column directly but use *, it shows column names in the result, but when I specify it, its not showing?

> result:  `{"X" : [1], "Y" : [{"bb":2}], "Z" : [{"cc":3,"dd":4}]}`

2. How (if possible) to set custom alias for column? So for example result would be

> `Z" : [{"custom1":3,"custom2":4}]}`

3. How to put values from different tables into single json_agg? I tried few methods but failed, e.g.

> ```
>  select json_build_object('XYZ', (select json_agg(CD.*, A.*) from Table_CD CD, Table_A A))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I almost find solution but if any table returns more than 1 row, the results are multiplied, how to avoid it?

```
WITH TableA as (select unnest(array[1,2,3,4]) as AA),
TableB AS (select 2 as BB)

SELECT  
json_build_object(
'Object1', json_agg(json_build_object('Value_1', AA)) 
,'Object2', json_agg(json_build_object('Value_2', BB)) 
)
FROM TableA A
 JOIN TableB B ON TRUE
```